# Flutter 2.5 format strange on vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm learning flutter, as i know, child shoud be on the right of parent for easy understand, because it make the child "inside" parent, like this

[image]

But with flutter 2.5, on vscode, it format like this, this make me hard to read and determine which is parent, because, child on left side

[image]

How can i fix this ?? i remember last time i use flutter, maybe 1.2, it not look like this

Thank you a lots

Comment: put a comma after every closing bracket or parentheses.

Comment: That actually the answer, wish i can accecpt your answer, thank bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very easy after each widget simply put "," and vsCode will all formate your code:  EG:-

```
  body:Column(

     children:[

         Container(
             child:Text("hello"),
         ),
         ],
```

)